# Wordpress - query 5 posts with a specific post in top

Tags: php, query

Many searches and tests but in vain, I need an expert to rescue me.

I need a custom post query in worpdress, which returns only 5 posts starting from a specific post. In other terms, there is a div in single.php where i need  the list of 5 posts starting from the current post (the post returned by single.php)

I hope I was clear thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `get_adjacent_post()` and the filter `get_previous_post_where` or `get_next_post_where`.  You'll call `get_adjacent_post()` as normal, but you'll need to change the `LIMIT` to 5, using the filter.

I wasn't sure from the question whether or not you wanted to have the current post be first. If you do, you'll need to set the `LIMIT` to 4 and then use the current postdata to generate the first post.

I would create an array of post ids, and then use `get_post()` when you iterate through them, as I believe that `get_adjacent_post()` will return raw rows from the database.

Comment: sorry for the delay in answer, thank you I am going to test this solution starting from  now and feedback

Comment: Frankly i dont know how to use get-previous_post_where there is no doc on internet, in addition they say this hook is renamed.  can u please give me more details if possible, thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual hook name is [`get_{$adjacent}_post_where`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/get_%7B$adjacent%7D_post_where). Have you gone and actually looked at the source for `get_adjacent_post()`? It's been quite some time since I wrote this answer, and I did not write it off the top of my head, I had to research it, so it'll probably be about as quick for you to figure it out as it will for me. If you're having a particular issue with it, I can help with that, but I try to avoid just giving code, as I feel it contributes to a lack of understanding in the community.

Comment: I was needing one year science and experience to understand this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep resetting the $post variable to advance the loops post counter.

Use something like this:

```
    global $post;
    get_header(); ?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
        /* Run the loop to output the post.
         * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
         * called loop-single.php and that will be used instead.
         */
        if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()): the_post();
            the_title();
            for($i = 0;$i < 4;$i++)
            {
                $post = get_next_post();
                setup_postdata($post);
                if(!empty($post))
                {
                    echo '<br/>';
                    the_title();
                    //or whatever code you need to output
                }
                else
                {
                    //no next post found
                }
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: sorry for the delay in answer, thank you I am going to test this solution starting from now and feedback